# Image Upload takes a lot of time to save in database

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server

I encountered a problem that when i upload an image , it takes a lot of time to upload it even if its only 1MB.

My Upload process is first use a `<input type='file'>` then convert the uploaded image to base64, convert it to byte then saving it to the database with `image` data type.

This is my SQL(Stored Proc):

```sql
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM VisitationLogs_BVL where UserIdx = @UserIdx and OutletIdx = @OutletIdx and convert(varchar, DateVisited, 23) = convert(varchar, getdate(), 23))
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 'Result'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO VisitationLogs_BVL(UserIdx,OutletIdx,CashierUser,IPAddress,Remarks,[Image])
        VALUES(@UserIdx,@OutletIdx,@CashierUser,@IPAddress,@Remarks,@image)
        SELECT @@ROWCOUNT Result, SCOPE_IDENTITY() AssignIdx
    END
```

Comment: I would use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example) with AJAX to send the file to your Server. Then you can access the file like you normally would, saving the file as a file to your Server, whilst saving the data for that filename separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will suggest you not to store the image in database. Instead you can save the image in your server and you can store the path of the image in database. Or else you can also use Azure Blob storage to save the image.

Comment: How if i already started saving the images as byte? There will be a problem in getting images when i change the way insert the image.

Answer (score 1):

Storing images in the database is a big no because it uses alot of resources. and by converting the image to base64 you're using more resources, the best way to store images is to store them in a CDN like amazon s3 because then you're letting amazon take care of the whole upload process which won't put a toll on your database and your server. once you upload the image to s3 you can then get the url of it and just display it in your html. this is the most efficient way to store images using CDN will also ensure your images are cached across the world.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly discouraged to store images in a SQL database as it will hugely reduce the performance. The recommended way is to store them as pure image files, store only the path in the database. Then use a simple http server to serve those static files.

More info: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem

Comment: The linked article is 13 years old. I know this subject is still relevant, but database capabilities are evolving all the time.

Comment: @bb who cares the age of article, when it contains facts which are still valid